# JTextArea text disappears

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm making a chess program for a project. I'm trying to add a move history box to the side of the board. The move history works fine, and the data is properly sent to the text area, but the text inside the JTextArea disappears while the AI is thinking about his move.

```
public void aiMove(){
  if (!playing){ return; }
  paintImmediately(0,0,totalX,totalY);
  ai = eve.getMove(chess,wtm,aiOut);   //text disappears here
  chess.makeMove(ai);
  wtm = !wtm;
  humanMove = true;
  writeMove(ai);                   //updates move history, text reappears here
  playing = stillPlaying();
  repaint();
}

private void writeMove(Move move){
  char c = "abcdefgh".charAt(7-move.fromY);
  char h ="abcdefgh".charAt(7-move.toY);
  String s = Character.toString(c)+(move.fromX+1)+" - "+Character.toString(h)+(move.toX+1)+"  ";
  if (!wtm){
    String q = chess.getFullMove()+".  "+s+"  ";
    moves.setText(moves.getText()+q);
  }
  else {
    moves.setText(moves.getText()+s+"\n");
  }
}
```

Here's a print screen of what's happening.
http://s13.postimage.org/mh7hltfk7/JText_Area_disappear.png

---

**SOLVED**
Thanks to all replies. I changed aiMove() so it creates a thread. Here is what I did.

Attempt #3... swing is still so foreign to me. I didn't want to change writeMove to getMove or I would have to rewrite the human's turn slightly. Since the project is essentially done, I am trying to avoid as much work as possible :)
The GUI is entirely optional anyways, I was just doing it for fun, and to try and learn a bit of swing.

```
public void aiMove(){
  if (!playing){ return; }
  if (!aiThread.isAlive()){
    aiThread = new Thread(){
      public void run(){
        ai = eve.getMove(chess,wtm,aiOut);
        chess.makeMove(ai);
        wtm = !wtm;
        humanMove = true;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
            writeMove(ai);
          }
        });
        repaint();
        playing = stillPlaying();
      }
    };
    aiThread.start();
  }
}
```

It also fixed a problem I had before, in that if I were to hold down the 'a' key (force ai move), it would queue up many forced ai moves. Now that doesn't happen.

Comment: Running time consuming tasks in separate threads will avoid GUI freezing up.

Comment: I am not sure if it is what is happening, but you should use the main thread only for GUI manipulation, because GUI will be refreshed by this thread. Bussiness logic (specially if it can take a while to complete) should be in a separate thread.

Comment: Your updated code violates the threading rules Swing - *thou shalt not update any UI element from any thread other than the Event Dispatching Thread* - Check out David's answer as he provides important pointers as how to fix these problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your AI thinking is CPU intensive/time consuming, thus it is considered a *long running task*. You should not do *long running tasks* on GUI Event Dispatch Thread as this will cause the UI to seem frozen and thus only show updates after the task has finished.

Fortunately there are 2 different approaches you could use:

- Use a [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which as the tutorial states:

> The SwingWorker subclass can define a method, done, which is
>   automatically invoked on the event dispatch thread when the background
>   task is finished.
>
> SwingWorker implements java.util.concurrent.Future.
>   This interface allows the background task to provide a return value to
>   the other thread. Other methods in this interface allow cancellation
>   of the background task and discovering whether the background task has
>   finished or been cancelled.
>
> The background task can provide
>   intermediate results by invoking SwingWorker.publish, causing
>   SwingWorker.process to be invoked from the event dispatch thread.
>
> The background task can define bound properties. Changes to these
>   properties trigger events, causing event-handling methods to be
>   invoked on the event dispatch thread.

- Alternatively create separate `Thread` for AI thinking and wrap `setText` call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...);`

  ```
  Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
      }
  });
  t.start();
  ```

**UPDATE**

After reading MadProgrammers comment (+1 to it) please remember to create/manipulate your GUI/Swing components on EDT via the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..)` block. You can read more on it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

**UPDATE 2:**

That edit is defeating the point, the only call on EDT in `SwingUtilitites` block should be the `setText` or atleast only code that manipulates a Swing component i.e

```
public void aiMove(){
  if (!playing){ return; } 
  if (!aiThread.isAlive()){  //originally initialized by constructor
    aiThread = new Thread(){
      public void run(){
            ai = eve.getMove(chess,wtm,aiOut);
            chess.makeMove(ai);
            wtm = !wtm;
            humanMove = true;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
            writeMove(ai);
          }
        });
        repaint();
        playing = stillPlaying();
      }
    };
    aiThread.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: @twentylemon sorry the getMove update was really not needed. Hence I edited it out. I see you updated your code so it must still be giving problems? Make sure you create your jframe and other components on edt, this can usually be solved by wrapping call to the creation the jframe in SwingUtilities.invokeXXX block. If still it does not work post an SSCCE

Comment: No, the problem is solved. I updated it for anyone else who has the same problem as I had. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @twentylemon Glad it works...if this is the answer please tick the check mark next to this post to show it as the answer and solved.